# How to add label to point without marker displaying in QGIS with python

Tags: qgis, python

I'm using a python script to manipulate the display of shapefiles in QGis.

My code basically selects an active layer and sets a field as the label of the point. Like this:

```
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.readFromLayer(layer)
label.enabled = True
label.fieldName = 'objnam'
label.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
label.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'8','') 
label.writeToLayer(layer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

This give's me the following result:

[image: Text label overlapping a default point marker]

I would like to add code so that the coloured marker will not be visible.
I've tried adding the following above my code in attempt to make the marker transparent:

```
renderer = layer.rendererV2()
symbol = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'style':'solid', 'color': '255,255,255,0', 'style_border':'no'})
renderer.setSymbol(symbol)
```

But this seems to do nothing.
I have a feeling that I misunderstand how the symbol layer works.
Any help or guidance is welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Size should be 0. Just add this parameter to the params dictionary like below:

```
symbol = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'size':'0'})
```

Comment: This did not work.

Comment: So try only with {'size':'0'} it works for me.

Comment: Still no luck. I'm using 2.8.3-Wein on Ubuntu. Will investigate more.

Comment: okay, on it's own this works. I just need to find out why it's not working within the rest of my script. I keep getting a 'QgsRuleBasedRendererV2' object has no attribute 'setSymbol'

Comment: So the moment I try to remove the marker while doing rule based rendering I get an error.