# Using "Ruled Based Render" to display labels without the marker with python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python

I'm writing a script to load and manipulate some shapefiles. 
Unlike my [previous question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189406/how-to-add-label-to-point-without-marker-displaying-in-qgis-with-python/189416#189416) I now need to display labels only on certain zoom levels. My usual result is that the previous formatting gets over written after a rule has been set.

Outside of the rule set up I can display a point (without a marker) like this:

```
rendererP = layer.rendererV2()
symbolP = QgsFillSymbolV2.createSimple({'size':'0'})
rendererP.setSymbol(symbolP)
label = QgsPalLayerSettings()
label.readFromLayer(layer)
label.enabled = True
label.fieldName = 'Variable'
label.setDataDefinedProperty(QgsPalLayerSettings.Size,True,True,'6','') label.placement= QgsPalLayerSettings.OverPoint
label.writeToLayer(layer)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

I'm using the following to set up the display on certain zoom levels:

```
symbol = QgsSymbolV2.defaultSymbol(layer.geometryType())
renderer = QgsRuleBasedRendererV2(symbol)
root_rule = renderer.rootRule()
## copy the rule to edit
rule = root_rule.children()[0].clone()
rule.setScaleMinDenom(1000000)
rule.setScaleMaxDenom(4000000) 
root_rule.appendChild(rule)
## delete the default rule
root_rule.removeChildAt(0)
## apply the renderer to the layer
layer.setRendererV2(renderer)
```

But the moment I attempt to apply the zoom level rules to this layer the markers returns.
Can anyone give me some guidance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add label to point without marker displaying in QGIS with python](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189406/how-to-add-label-to-point-without-marker-displaying-in-qgis-with-python)

Comment: Edited to explain why this question is different than flag 'duplicate'